# RailsTutorial.org Exercise 9.6.2 - using session instead of cookies for user sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

RailsTutorial.org Exercise 9.6.2: I'm trying to sign in with cookies if a 'Stay signed in' checkbox is checked, otherwise sign in with a session. Starting from Michael Hartl's code, I've made the following changes:

I've added this code to the sign-in form in views > sessions > new.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.check_box :stay_signed_in %> Stay signed in?
</div>
```

I've added this one line in the sessions controller:

```
def create
  session[:staysignedin] = (params[:session][:stay_signed_in] == "1") ? true : false
  ...
end
```

And I've made the following alterations in the Sessions Helper:

```
def sign_in(user)
  if session[:staysignedin]
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
  else
    session[:userid] = user.id
  end
  self.current_user = user
end

def sign_out
  if session[:staysignedin]
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  else
    session[:userid] = nil
    session[:staysignedin] = nil
  end
  self.current_user = nil
end

def user_from_remember_token
  session[:staysignedin] ? User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token) : User.find_by_id(session[:userid])
end
```

The problem is that it always behaves as if the checkbox is unchecked, always signing in using session rather than cookies, even when the checkbox is checked, and I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.nimweb.it/web-development/ruby-on-rails-web-development/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-exercise-9-6-2-rails-session/

Comment: Explain more your suggestion, not only paste link